# Difference between "restricted" and "limited"

Tags: word-choice

I'm a non-native speaker of English. When I want to express the meaning of “Something，especially for some techniques, is not widely used yet ” in my paper, which word would be better? I don't quite understand the difference between these two words. Could you help me, please?

Comment: I think a clear example of where you want to use "restricted" or "limited" would help.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Here's the sentence that I wanna to write: "However, extensive screen of tuberculosis remains limited". Followed which, I wanna to explain that this is because of the technology is not mature enough. In this case, could you please help me which word is prefer?

Comment: **Limited** *tends* to be used where the thing or person has its own limitations; **restricted** *tends* to be used where an exterior force, e.g. an authority or rules, prevents certain uses.

Comment: Choose one of these: I want to express, OR, I wanna express. WANNA TO EXPRESS is neither here, nor there.

Comment: have you checked some online dictionaries for both definitions, sample sentences, and possible usage notes? this site is not intended to replace dictionaries, which should be among the first resources you consult. have a nice virus free day